# How to replace blank space zero?

Tags: awk, gsub

I have a file:

```
 nr  kl1  kl2  kl3  kl4 
 d1  15   58   63   58 
 d2       3    3      
 d3  3         8    0
```

I want to print:

```
 nr  kl1  kl2  kl3  kl4 
 d1  15   58   63   58 
 d2  0    3    3    0  
 d3  3    0    8    0
```

I tried gsub solution, but it does not work.

```
awk '{gsub(/ /, 0, $2); print }' file
```

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

**Ed Morton** solution works on gawk, but it does not work on mawk.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS="5 5 5 5 5"; OFS="" }NR>1 {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i=sprintf("%-5d",$i)}{ sub(/ +$/,""); print }' file
 nr  kl1  kl2  kl3  kl4
 d1  15   58   63   58
 d2  0    3    3    0
 d3  3    0    8    0
```

.

```
$ mawk 'BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS="5 5 5 5 5"; OFS="" }NR>1 {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i=sprintf("%-5d",$i)}{ sub(/ +$/,""); print }' file 
 nr  kl1  kl2  kl3  kl4
d115   58   63   58
d23    3
d33    8    0
```

How to do the same, but the mawk?

Comment: does the file use tabs to separate the fields?

Comment: @beny23, Yes, the file does not use tabs to separate the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you tried didn't work because your fields aren't separated by spaces, they're a fixed width. Try this with GNU awk:

```
BEGIN{ FIELDWIDTHS="5 5 5 5 5"; OFS="" }

NR>1 {
   for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)
      $i=sprintf("%-5d",$i)
}
{ sub(/ +$/,""); print }
```

Comment: Thank you for a good answer. Your solution works to gawk, but it does not work on mawk. See my edit.

Comment: That's correct, I said it was a GNU awk solution. It's not worthwhile to figure out how to do it in mawk as mawk has a minimal set of functionality and should only be used if you have a highly performance critical problem to solve. Just install gawk.